# Does every real number have a decimal expansion?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, number-systems

Can every real number be written in decimal expansion?

I mean, can every real number $a$ be expressed as follows:
$$\text{For }\,  a \in \mathbb {R}^{+},\quad a=p+\frac{n_{1}}{10}+\frac{n_{2}}{10^{2}}+\cdots$$
$$\text{where }\,  n_{i} \in \mathbb N \quad  \text{and} \quad 0\le n_{i}<10, \;\; p \in \mathbb Z$$

Comment: If you have changed $n$ for $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, you don't need restrict $a$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every real number can be written as a decimal expansion.  For a proof, see Rudin *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (McGraw Hill 1976) p. 11.

Moreover, for every real number $r$ not of the form $\frac n{10^k}  (n,k\in \Bbb Z)$, the decimal expansion is unique.